# AppInventor - WebViewer - Access phone file

Tags: app-inventor

i've tried to create an app with AppInventor using WebViewer, starting from a website [www.aimsafe.it](http://www.aimsafe.it)
In this website i can upload file from phone/tablet/pc/camera.
Unfortunately, when i click the button into the app created for upload a file, no action is performed.
Someone can help me?

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow. Please first [take the tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour) and read [How to ask a good question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

You might want to edit your question and add a screenshot of your **relevant** blocks.

Answer (score 0):

The default webviewer does not offer a method to upload a file... you might want to use the [Custom WebView Extension](https://community.appinventor.mit.edu/t/customwebview-an-extended-form-of-web-viewer/9934?u=taifun) by vknow360